# What is the bracha for mushrooms?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, mushrooms

What bracha do you make on mushrooms?

Answer (score 8):

shehakol. 
But look at [this](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/mushroom/) fascinating article for more details!

Answer (score 2):

The bracha for mushrooms is Shehakol.
Reference: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehakol  "The Bracha Shehakol is recited over mushrooms."  Source cited: BI"H (Ben Ish Hai) Mattoh, halacha 6 (page 179)