# Picking mushrooms on shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, mushrooms

Is one allowed to pick mushrooms from where they grew on shabbos?

To provide some context:

> The Talmud (Berachos 40b) states that although mushrooms grow on the ground, the proper Beracha is nonetheless Shehakol, the general Beracha for foods that are not plants. The Talmud explains that although mushrooms do indeed grow on the ground, they are exceptional in that they do not derive their primary nutrition from the soil, as do other plants. [Interestingly, the Aruch Hashulchan (204:5), among others, holds that if one made a mistake and recited HoAdama on mushrooms, it would be acceptable, since the Talmud does consider mushrooms to be Gidulei Karka (growths of the ground), although they do not derive their sustenance from it.]

http://www.kashrut.com/articles/mushroom/

Comment: I don't see the link between the issue of the proper blessing for mushrooms and their use on shabbat. Why would you think that picking mushrooms is different from picking wheat or flowers? Is it because of the source of their nutrition?

Comment: @RonP Since it's not considered as a "plant" in some regards, maybe you can pick it on Shabbos

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13810/759

Comment: Two possible prohibitions, perhaps: tearing - mushrooms tend to grow roots which you may be tearing up from the ground. Nolad - it may have been something formed on Shabbat itself.

Comment: And gathering too

Comment: @DanF they don't have roots

Comment: @user613 not "roots" as trees do. But they have some type of "spore" system or something that makes them stick to the ground or tree. Otherwise they would easily fly away in the wind. When I've picked mushrooms in almost every case, grass or dirt comes with it, so unless I'm extremely careful, something from the ground is torn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kotzer#cite_ref-7):

> It is forbidden to pick mushrooms or remove moss from a rock it is growing on (39 Melachos [Rabbi Ribiat, vol 2, pg 283], Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchata
>   26:10).

For an even earlier source, see also the [Babylonian Talmud](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.107b?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) (Shabbath [107b](http://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_107.html)-108a) which extends the prohibition in the case of fungi to places where harvesting plants would not be liable:

> Abaye said: He who plucks fungus from the handle of a pitcher is liable on account of uprooting something from the place of its growth. R. Oshaia objected: If one detaches [aught] from a perforated pot, he is culpable; if it is unperforated, he is exempt? — There, that is not its [normal place for] growing; but here this is its [normal place for] growing.

Comment: +1 for citing a valid "resource". I placed that word in quotes, intentionally, as in this case, Halachipedia quotes another source. I don't currently have access to Shemirat Shabbat. If you can access it and summarize what that says, it would greatly enhance your answer. Personally, I'd like to know what melachot are violated and why.

Comment: @DanF The reference (footnote number 7) is what is shown in the answer.

Comment: @DanF It is the melacha of Kotzer See [Rabbi Mansour on DailyHalacha.com](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=2447) who explains that the Melacha of Kotzer refers to detaching produce from the ground using a utensil such as a sickle and Tolesh, which is the Toldah of Kotzer, includes detaching produce from the ground with one's hands.

Comment: @sabbahillel Thanks. I think you should move your comment to an edit in the above answer. It seems to be useful info.

Comment: Mishna Brura 336, 34 said it. The explanation is that it is the natural way of growing and he want the growing. The fact that the mushroom is fixed to the ground and the fact that he do not keep his nourishment from earth are two separated topics.